# Return a dereferenced value of shared_ptr from a function

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, shared-ptr

Here is a rookie question. Is the following code safe?

```
boost::unordered_set<std::string> func()
{
      boost::shared_ptr<boost::unordered_set<std::string>> list =
              boost::make_shared<boost::unordered_set<std::string>>();

      /* Code to populate the shared_ptr to unordered_set goes here and I do
         populate my set. */

      return *list;
}
```

What will happen first? Copying/NRVO/moving or destruction of `shared_ptr` there by causing memory fault? If unsafe, what are my alternatives?

Comment: If the shared pointer is never going to be shared it's kind of pointless.  Is this a question about shared pointers (in which case you might need to expand your example) or is this more a question about return value optimizations?

Comment: You could as well have `boost::unordered_set<std::string> list;` and `return list;`, because all your `shared_ptr` does there is allocate some extra stuff on the heap, which is not optimal for your case unless you share the ownership of `shared_ptr` to somewhere else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens:

- A temporary copy of the pointed object is made. This is the return value of the function. The copy can not be elided.
- The local variables of the function, including the shared pointer are destroyed.
- When the shared pointer is destroyed, the refcount is decremented. If no copies of the shared pointer were made within the function, refocount will reach 0 and the pointed object is destroyed.

It is safe, but the use of dynamic allocation, and shared pointer seems *pointless* and the inefficiency of the copy may hurt performance if the set is large.

---

Since you haven't demonstrated any need for using the pointer, I suggest a simpler alternative:

```
boost::unordered_set<std::string> list;

/* Code to populate the unordered_set goes here and I do
     populate my set. */

return list;
```

NRVO can be applied to this and if it's not applied, the return value is constructed by move.

Answer (score 4):

> Copying/NRVO/moving or destruction of shared_ptr there by causing memory fault?

Well, let's think about it. Consider this function:

```
X foo() {
    X x;
    return x;
}
```

There are two potential orderings here, let's forget about copy elision.

1. `x` is copied into the return value, then `x` is destroyed.
2. `x` is destroyed, then `x` is copied into the return value.

The implication of (2) would be that such code would be undefined behavior, which would make it pretty much impossible to write a function at all - since you couldn't return any local variables. So from a language sanity design perspective, it had better be (1).

---

The explicit rule is in [stmt.return]:

> The copy-initialization of the result of the call **is sequenced before the destruction of temporaries** at the end of the full-expression established by the operand of the return statement, which, in turn, is sequenced before
>   the destruction of local variables (6.6) of the block enclosing the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your shared_ptr is not doing anything, you are not returning it, you are returning its contents, i.e. the unordered_set itself.
You should change your function to return the shared_ptr and return it by value.

You should probably be using std:: not boost (unless this is an old compiler).

Comment: I made a comment that I do populate my shared_ptr with a code.

Comment: But when you say *list it gets the contents of the shared pointer and that is what gets returned.  The shared_ptr objects itself is created locally on the stack of the function and destroyed when function returns -- it literally serves no purpose as written.